# why I should delete the temporary internet files (in ie9) and only then I can load data

Tags: javascript

I have  very strange problem - when you click a button I make an ajax call to an axis web service that gets data from PostgreSQL database and fills some inputs.

However, after I have fill the inputs with data when I click the button again nothing happens and I get no errors. Only when I delete the temporary internet files in ie9 can I load new data in my inputs.

This is the function that's executed when you click a button:

```
function fetchCompanyInfo() {
    var xmlhttp = createXMLHttpRequest();
    var request = "http://localhost:9090/verifydatabase/services/verifydatabase/getData";

    xmlhttp.open("GET", request, true);
    handleStateChangeFetchInfo(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function handleStateChangeFetchInfo(xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var xmlObj = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            var textXML = xmlObj.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;

            if (window.DOMParser) {
                parser = new DOMParser();
                var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(textXML, "text/xml");
            } else {
                var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(textXML);
            }


            var rows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("row");

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");

                var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("colunm");

                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                    if (cols[j].getAttribute("colname") == "biz_subject") {
                        document.getElementById("old_biz_subject").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                        document.getElementById("txbbiz_subject").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                    } else
                    if (cols[j].getAttribute("colname") == "company_type") {
                        document.getElementById("old_company_type").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                        document.getElementById("txbcompany_type").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                    } else
                    if (cols[j].getAttribute("colname") == "country") {
                        document.getElementById("old_country").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                        document.getElementById("txbcountry").value = "Р България";
                    } else
                    if (cols[j].getAttribute("colname") == "nace_code") {
                        document.getElementById("old_nace_code").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                        document.getElementById("txbnacecode").value = cols[j].getAttribute("colvalue");
                    }

                }
            }
            pinCompanyLocation(document.getElementById("old_location").value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please run your post through an English-language spell checker before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your AJAX maybe getting cached? Try adding a timestamp to the URL:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", request + "?timestamp=" + (+new Date), true);
```

Comment: it solved my problem. Can you explain why my ajax call is getting cached

Comment: It has to do with the HTTP response headers returned by the server. Depending on how headers like "Cache-Control", and "Expires" are set, the browser will decide to cache the result, just like it does for images, JS, CSS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but from your description it sounds like you're trying to update values in some text boxes from a remote service when someone clicks a button. It looks like your script is actually creating the text boxes too, though. I suspect that the second time someone clicks your button, it's failing to create the fields because they already exist in the DOM. I'm presuming it works after your "clear the cache" because you're probably reloading the page too.